# How to embed Maths Symbols and Equations in Ajax Editor

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, math, symbols

I am trying to embed Maths Symbols and Equations in Ajax Editor.
or provide some solution to implement maths symbols and equations in my application using rich textbox or some controls/plugins.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend http://www.mathjax.org/, which is endorsed by many websites (ie project Euclid).

Comment: thanks. but i am unable to download the files. i will try later again. i hope it is freeware.

Comment: It is an open source software. (BTW, I'll be glad if you'll accept the answer if you found it helpful, click on the V to the left).